# PHP replace each fill colour of <circle> between <g> tag with specific ID

Tags: php, replace, tags, preg-replace

Sorry if the title isn't that great.

I'm using PHP to write a script that will change the fill color of a `<circle>` if it is inside a `<g>` with a specific id.

Here is the specific string:

```
<g id="stroke">
<circle cx="6.628mm" cy="23.164mm" r="1.50mm"  fill="#B8BBC0" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.282mm"/>
<circle cx="3.920mm" cy="20.170mm" r="1.50mm"  fill="#B8BBC0" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.282mm"/>
</g>
<g id="fill" style="visibility: hidden;">
<circle cx="22.593mm" cy="31.429mm" r="1.50mm"  fill="#B8BBC0" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.282mm" data-isfill="yes"/>
<circle cx="22.593mm" cy="27.381mm" r="1.50mm"  fill="#B8BBC0" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.282mm" data-isfill="yes"/>
</g>
```

So, in my thoughts are:

```
Change fill="#B8BBC0" to fill="#000000" IF inside <g id="stroke">
Change fill="#B8BBC0" to fill="#FFFFFF" IF inside <g id="fill">
```

I'm not exactly sure on the best methods to do this. I know the basics of replace() but I don't know how to write the code to replace between two tags with a specific id. Could anyone help me write this?

Comment: What do you want from us?

Comment: Please see edit - Ideally I need help writing the script.

Comment: So far just replacing #B8BBC0 to #000000 which works fine but I don't know which functions to use to change it between the '<g id="">' tag

Comment: You can use PHP's DOM classes/functions to do this.

Comment: So I could use something like setAttribute('fill', '#000000') but how can I set an attribute that is within a specific '<g>' ?

Comment: learn about xmlPath(searching tag using id)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using the `DOMDocument`:

```
$data = <<<DATA
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
<g id="stroke">
<circle cx="6.628mm" cy="23.164mm" r="1.50mm"  fill="#B8BBC0" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.282mm"/>
<circle cx="3.920mm" cy="20.170mm" r="1.50mm"  fill="#B8BBC0" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.282mm"/>
</g>
<g id="fill" style="visibility: hidden;">
<circle cx="22.593mm" cy="31.429mm" r="1.50mm"  fill="#B8BBC0" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.282mm" data-isfill="yes"/>
<circle cx="22.593mm" cy="27.381mm" r="1.50mm"  fill="#B8BBC0" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.282mm" data-isfill="yes"/>
</g>
</root>
DATA;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($data);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$gstrokes = $xpath->query('//g[@id="stroke"]/circle[@fill]'); // Get CIRCLEs (with fill attribute) inside G with ID "stroke"
foreach($gstrokes as $c) {                  // Loop through all CIRCLEs found
   $c->setAttribute('fill', '#000000');     // Set fill="#000000"
}
$gstrokes = $xpath->query('//g[@id="fill"]/circle[@fill]'); // Get CIRCLEs (with fill attribute) inside G with ID "fill"
foreach($gstrokes as $c) {                  // Loop through all CIRCLEs found
   $c->setAttribute('fill', '#FFFFFF');     // Set fill="#000000"
}

echo $dom->saveXML();                       // Save XML
```

See the [online PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/MZHag)

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
<g id="stroke">
<circle cx="6.628mm" cy="23.164mm" r="1.50mm" fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.282mm"/>
<circle cx="3.920mm" cy="20.170mm" r="1.50mm" fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.282mm"/>
</g>
<g id="fill" style="visibility: hidden;">
<circle cx="22.593mm" cy="31.429mm" r="1.50mm" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.282mm" data-isfill="yes"/>
<circle cx="22.593mm" cy="27.381mm" r="1.50mm" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.282mm" data-isfill="yes"/>
</g>
</root>
```